# Error of midpoint method for functions that are not twice-differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, na.numerical-analysis

All of the bounds I've seen for the error of the midpoint method of integration are expressed in terms of the second derivative of the function.  What bounds are available when the function is not twice-differentiable?  In particular, is it the case that for every continuous function $f$ on $[0,1]$, the midpoint method of estimating $\int_0^1 f(x)\:  dx$ has error $o(1/n)$?  If the answer to this last question is "no" (and I'm pretty sure it is, unless I've misunderstood the example Carnahan gave in response to my earlier question [Dependence of error on mesh for Riemann sums](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13344/dependence-of-error-on-mesh-for-riemann-sums)), does the answer change to "yes" if we assume that $f$ has bounded variation? That $f$ is monotone?

Comment: As an example, consider the piecewise linear function on $[0,1]$ with $f(0)=0$, $f(1/2)=1$, and $f(1)=0$, linear on $[0,1/2]$ and $[1/2,1]$.  For $n$ even, the error is 0; for n odd, the error is $1/2n^2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the function is monotone, then the error for the midpoint approximation with $n$ intervals is at most $\frac{f(1)-f(0)}{2n}$.  Say we know $f$ is increasing and the values at the midpoints, $f(m_i)$ for $i=1,\dots n$, as well as $f(0)$ and $f(1)$, are known.  Then the $g_L$ with the smallest integral that satisfies those constraints (not continuous, but arbitrarily closely approximated by continuous functions) is the stepwise function $$g_L(x) = f(m_i) \text{ whenever } m_i\leq x < m_{i+1}$$ where by convention $m_0 = 0$ and $m_{n+1}=1$.  Similarly, the function with the largest integral that satisfies these constraints is
$$g_U(x) = f(m_{i+1}) \text{ whenever } m_i < x \leq m_{i+1}$$
So we have $$\int_0^1 g_L(x) dx \leq \int_0^1 f(x)dx \leq \int_0^1 g_U(x)dx$$
Note that the functions $g_L$ and $g_M$ depend on $f$ and $n$, but $f$ does not depend on $n$.
Then $$\int_0^1 g_L(x) dx = \sum_{i=0}^{n} (m_{i+1} - m_i)f(m_i) = \frac{1}{2n}f(0) + \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} f(m_i) + \frac{1}{2n} f(m_n)$$ and a similar calculation gives $\int_0^1 g_U(x) dx$.

Subtracting the midpoint approximation from the integral inequality above gives $$\frac{f(0)-f(m_n)}{2n} \leq \int_0^1 f(x) dx - \frac{1}{n}\sum_i f(m_i) \leq \frac{f(1) - f(m_1)}{2n}$$ and one can see that the magnitude of the error is bounded by $\frac{f(1)-f(0)}{2n}$.

If $f$ is of bounded variation, then $f = f^+ - f^-$ where each summand is monotone increasing.  Since taking integrals and taking midpoint approximations both commute with finite sums, the total error is bounded by $\frac{f^+(1)-f^+(0) + f^-(1) - f^-(0)}{2n}$.  Note that the numerator is the total variation of the function.

**EDIT:  The following was added on 2/17/14.**

To see that $O(1/n)$ is the best possible, consider the following construction of a continuous monotone increasing function $f$ with $f(0)=0, f(1)=1$, and for infinitely many $n$, the midpoint approximation at $n$ has error greater than $\frac{1}{4n}$.  The function is constructed in stages, similar to the Cantor function.

First we mess up the approximation for $n=2$.  Since the samples are taken at $\frac{1}{4}$ and $\frac{3}{4}$, define $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 &\text{ if } x \in [0,\frac{1}{4}] \\ \frac{1}{2} &\text{ if } x \in [\frac{1}{4}+\varepsilon_1, \frac{3}{4}] \\ 1 & \text{ if } x \in [\frac{3}{4}+\varepsilon_1, 1]\end{cases}$$ where $\varepsilon_1<\frac{1}{4}$ will be chosen soon.  Regardless of the choice for $\varepsilon_1$, the midpoint approximation at $n=2$ is $\frac{1}{4}$.  The integral of the function (based on its values where it has been defined so far) is at least $\frac{1}{2} - \frac{3}{2}\varepsilon_1$.  So by choosing $\varepsilon_1$ small enough, we can guarantee an error of at least $\frac{1}{8}$.

It is convenient to make $\varepsilon_1$ of the form $2^{-k_1}$.  Then the $2^{k_1+1}$ approximation will be perfect on all but four $\varepsilon_1/2$-length intervals, in two pairs.  Now we have set ourselves up to recurse, messing up the $2^{k_1+1}$ midpoint approximation by putting in each $\varepsilon_1$-sized gap an appropriate increasing function of variation $\frac{1}{2}$ which is badly under-approximated by the pair of values it contributes to the overall approximation.

That is, we may define
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 &\text{ if } x - \frac{1}{4} \in [0,\frac{\varepsilon_1}{4}] \\ \frac{1}{4} &\text{ if } x-\frac{1}{4} \in [\frac{\varepsilon_1}{4} + \varepsilon_2, \frac{3\varepsilon_1}{4}] \\ \frac{1}{2} & \text{ if } x-\frac{1}{4} \in [\frac{3\varepsilon_1}{4} + \varepsilon_2, \varepsilon_1]\end{cases}$$ where $\varepsilon_2$ will be chosen soon.  The $2^{k_1+1}$ approximation estimates the integral of $f$ on $[\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{4}+\varepsilon_1]$ to be $\frac{\varepsilon_1}{8}$, but the actual integral is at least $\frac{\varepsilon_1}{4} - \frac{3}{2}\varepsilon_2$, so by choosing $\varepsilon_2$ sufficiently small, we can guarantee that the error is at least $\frac{\varepsilon_1}{16}$.  By defining $f$ analogously on $[\frac{3}{4},\frac{3}{4}+\varepsilon_1]$ (choosing the same $\varepsilon_2$, but all the values are shifted up by $\frac{1}{2}$), we can double the total error to at least $\frac{\varepsilon_1}{8} = \frac{1}{4\cdot 2^{k_1+1}}$.

Now there are four gaps of size $\varepsilon_2$, each of which should support an increasing function of variation $\frac{1}{4}$.  Recurse.

Comment: This addresses my first question ("What bounds are available?") but it's not clear to me that it resolves the question of whether, for each particular $f$, the error of the midpoint method is $o(1/n)$. Note that in Westrick's example, the function $f$ depends on $n$.

Comment: Hi James.  I improved the notation and added some details.  (The function $f$ does not depend on $n$.) Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Can Westrick (or anyone else) come up with a function $f$ for which the error of the midpoint method fails to be $o(1/n)$?  If $f$ is a continuous piecewise linear function on $[0,1]$ with $k$ "breakpoints" (points at which the second derivative is undefined), and one divides $[0,1]$ in to $n$ subintervals of width $1/n$, then I can show that the error of the midpoint method is $o(1/n)$.  Note that $k$ and $n$ play very different roles here.  I agree that if $k$ is allowed to increase as $n$ does, e.g. if we take $k=n$, bad things happen, but then we're not talking about a fixed $f$ anymore.

Comment: Now I think I understand your previous comments -- you are just as interested in the "$o$" as the "$1/n$".  I added a nasty function for which the error fails to be $o(1/n)$.

Comment: I still can't help thinking that there's a big gap between $O(1/n^3)$ (the behavior of the error that's guaranteed as long as the second derivative of $f$ is bounded) and $O(1/n)$, and suspecting that some hypothesis on $f$ stronger than mere continuity but considerably weaker than boundedness of the second derivative would imply that the error falls faster than $1/n$.  But if nobody knows of results along these lines, I guess that's just how it is.

Comment: There are certainly some hypotheses one could add to get rid of the kind of bad behavior above.  For a very weak example, I don't know how to make an $O(1/n)$ convergence with an absolutely continuity restriction.

If you're satisfied with my answer, though, I hope you will accept it :-)

Comment: I gratefully accept it.  I'll turn my follow-up question into a separate post; see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/157988/error-of-midpoint-method-for-differentiable-functions .  (Instead of absolutely continuity, I'll go for differentiability, which not only is stronger but also is probably easier to work with if one is looking for positive results as opposed to counterexamples.)

Comment: I meant with the checkbox, but in any case I'm glad it helped.